# Array.filter is not working properly for the array, include objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an Array like this.
[image]

I need branchId only.so I use the filter method to filter this array and store branchId in react state.

```
 const [branchID,setBranchID]=React.useState([]);
 const tempTwo=[
       {
          branchId: "61b25e0ae177d62ce4cb3b47",
          branchName: "Shopzier Malabe Branch"
       },
       {
          branchId: "61aa4f802aed6f0022102a99"
          branchName: "Test Branch New Update"
      },
      {
         branchId: "619f346f17b5522b184d5c01",
         branchName: "Shopzier Main Branch Update Trest12"
      }
   ]
 React.useEffect(()=>{
    setBranchID([...tempTwo.filter(item=>item.branchId)])
  },[])
```

But when I console log branchID, It prints my full array, not branchID only.
How can I filter branchID from my Object array. I have no idea what is wrong and why is this happening. If anyone can help me with this, I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: filter works exactly as expected. Maybe you need `map`?

Comment: You are using the wrong array method, instead you should use `tempTwo.map(item => item.branchId)`
Map method will return a new array and you don't need spread operator too

Comment: Did you intend to use `.map` instead? `tempTwo.map(i => i.branchId)`

Comment: Use `map` not `filter`

Comment: Thanks all for your answer.  I had the wrong idea about the filter method till now.❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what filter function actually does.

You should use the map operator instead to **extract** a property  from your array, like this:

```
 React.useEffect(()=>{
    setBranchID([...tempTwo.map(item=>item.branchId)])
  },[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had the wrong idea about the filter method till now.❤️

Comment: You don't need to spread as well as `map()` returns a new array already. `setBranchID(tempTwo.map(item=>item.branchId))`

Answer (score 1):

`Filter` is used to filter out all the objects that matches given condition, in your case, the has an id. To get only the id from list you need to use `map`

```
const idList = tempTwo.map(item=> item.branchId)
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from the already existing one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505652/7376590

Comment: Am sorry about that, didn't see the first answer, I think we posted almost at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to do that.
You can do this using a map function and your matchId to extract data from the array.

```
const [branchID,setBranchID]=React.useState("");
 const tempTwo=[
       {
          branchId: "61b25e0ae177d62ce4cb3b47",
          branchName: "Shopzier Malabe Branch"
       },
       {
          branchId: "61aa4f802aed6f0022102a99"
          branchName: "Test Branch New Update"
      },
      {
         branchId: "619f346f17b5522b184d5c01",
         branchName: "Shopzier Main Branch Update Trest12"
      }
   ]
 React.useEffect(()=>{
    tempTwo.map((branchData, i) => {
      //match your branch id value
      if (branchData.branchId === some_id) {
        setBranchID(branchData.branchId)
      }
    })
  },[])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and more details about my question.❤️